# USB passthrough not working using virt-manager/qemu

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, usb, virt-manager

I have created a virtual machine using virt-manager 1.3.2 and wanted to add a USB device. However, the USB device does not show up in the guest (Debian) when using `lsusb`. In another virtual machine that I created without virt-manager, USB passthrough works. virt-manager starts the VM using this command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name deb8qtm1 -S -machine pc-i440fx-xenial,accel=kvm,usb=off -cpu Nehalem -m 1024 -realtime mlock=off -smp 4,sockets=4,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid 08d8f6d3-10d0-49c6-81e5-642651536a57 -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-deb8qtm1/monitor.sock,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=discard -no-hpet -no-shutdown -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s3=1 -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s4=1 -boot strict=on -device nec-usb-xhci,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5 -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/deb8qtm1.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0 -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 -drive if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,readonly=on -device ide-cd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0 -netdev tap,fd=26,id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=28 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:1e:fe:f8,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -chardev spicevmc,id=charchannel0,name=vdagent -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 -device usb-tablet,id=input0 -spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing,image-compression=off,seamless-migration=on -device qxl-vga,id=video0,ram_size=67108864,vram_size=67108864,vgamem_mb=16,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 -device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir -device usb-redir,chardev=charredir0,id=redir0 -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir1,name=usbredir -device usb-redir,chardev=charredir1,id=redir1 -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=9,id=hostdev0 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x8 -msg timestamp=on
```

I suspect the cause is the "usb=off" argument. I have no clue how to tell virt-manager to start qemu-system-x86_64 without that argument.

Any hints?